# Grouping values in a string array matching a criteria in R

Tags: r, arrays, string, dataframe, grouping

I have a big data frame `df1` that has a column `Student` which has string values for students name, `Grades` with numeric values for the grades of an exam. Another data frame `df2` that has three columns `Class` numeric, `From` `To` as a range for the grade and `Count` that summarizes how many students has a specific grade between some value for a specific class.

As an example:

```
Stundent <- c("Mark", "Jhon", "Stuart", "Lillie", "Carl", "Jason", "Stewart","Jack")
Grades <- c(7,9,1,6,7,6,4,8)
df1 <- data.frame(Stundent,Grades)

Class <- c(101, 101, 201, 308, 507, 201, 507, 308)
from <- c(1,6,1,1,6,6,1,6)
to <- c(5,10,5,5,10,10,5,10)
Count <- c(0,2,1,0,1,1,1,2)
df2 <- data.frame(Class,from,to,Count)
df2 <- df2[order(df2$Class),]
```

And what I'm expecting is to get something like this

```
Students <- c("","Mark, Jhon", "Stuart", "Lillie", "","Carl, Jason", "Stewart", "Jack")
df3 <- data.frame(df2, Students)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what class the students in `df1` are in? Does the list of names in `df1` exactly match `df2` so that the first two names in `df1` must be in class 101 (the first 2 rows of `df2`)?

Comment: How do you match `df1` and `df2` ? Shouldn't there be another column in `df1` called `Class` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear.  Here is a `for` loop version.  Based on the expected output, it could be 'Stundent' from the 'df1' are allocated to each row of 'df2' 'Students' column by comparing the 'Grades' against the 'from', 'to' in 'df2' and the number of 'Stundent' selected are limited by the 'Count' value.  Once a 'Stundent' is  selected, it is not repeated again

```
tmpdat <- df1
tmpdat$Stundent <- as.character(tmpdat$Stundent)

df2$Students <- ""
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {

       if(df2$Count[i] >0 ) {
        st1 <- head(tmpdat$Stundent[tmpdat$Grades >= df2$from[i] & 
                                    tmpdat$Grades <= df2$to[i]], df2$Count[i])
        tmpdat <- tmpdat[!tmpdat$Stundent %in% st1, ]
        df2$Students[i] <- toString(st1) 

      }

  }




df2
#  Class from to Count    Students
#1   101    1  5     0            
#2   101    6 10     2  Mark, Jhon
#3   201    1  5     1      Stuart
#6   201    6 10     1      Lillie
#4   308    1  5     0            
#8   308    6 10     2 Carl, Jason
#5   507    6 10     1        Jack
#7   507    1  5     1     Stewart
```

In the expected output, the Jack and 'Stewart for 507 are switched.  From 'df1', Jack's Grades  is 8 and Stewart 4

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there should be another column in `df1` which would be `Class` identifying which student is in which `Class` because there is no information to match the data. If my assumption is not correct, let me know and I'll delete the answer.

```
#adding class column
df1$Class <- c(101, 101, 201, 201, 308, 308, 507, 507)
```

We can `left_join` `df1` and `df2` by `Class` and create comma-separated values of `Stundent` which are in range.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'Class') %>%
  group_by(Class, from, to) %>%
  summarise(Stundent = toString(Stundent[Grades >= from & Grades <= to]))


#  Class  from    to Stundent     
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
#1   101     1     5 ""           
#2   101     6    10 "Mark, Jhon" 
#3   201     1     5 "Stuart"     
#4   201     6    10 "Lillie"     
#5   308     1     5 ""           
#6   308     6    10 "Carl, Jason"
#7   507     1     5 "Stewart"    
#8   507     6    10 "Jack"
```